# AWS Lambda VPC ENI overflow

Tags: amazon-vpc, serverless-framework

My Lambda accesses resources on my VPC so as instructed in the documentation I've given the Lambda a role to create network interfaces. I was under the assumption that the ENI is reused but looks like every invocation is creating a new ENI which caused to throw an error

Lambda was not able to create an ENI in the VPC of the Lambda function because the limit for Network Interfaces has been reached.

My role has -ec2:* permissions like it said in the documentation.

Apart from manually deleting these ENIs periodically is there a better way?

Comment: can you provide more details of your serverless.yml?

Comment: Example of a provider in the serverless.yml: provider:
  ....
  iamRoleStatements:
     -
       Effect: Allow
       Action:
         - dynamodb:*
         - sns:*
         - ses:SendRawEmail
         - s3:*
         - lambda:InvokeFunction
         - execute-api:Invoke
         - ec2:*
       Resource: "*"
  vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
      - sg-58fe6520
    subnetIds:
      - subnet-a4e568c3
      - subnet-80f27fe7
      - subnet-37f77a50

Comment: You could add the extra information to the question itself, it will be more readable and will increase your chances of getting a response if still waiting for it.